# How to install ubuntu bash on windows 2012?

Tags: windows

I used to use ubuntu bash on windows 10 and want to install it on windows 2012 R2. But I couldn't find how to install it. Doesn't it support windows 2012?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/785647/install-bash-openssh-on-windows-server-2012 Check this link, I hope this will help.

Comment: Windows Subsystem for Linux is not available on Windows 2012.

Comment: Is it available to windows 2016?

Comment: @ZhaoYi Not currently, but [reportedly it will be](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloud/2017/05/10/windows-server-for-developers-news-from-microsoft-build-2017/).

Comment: great thanks. Could you post your answer then I can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ubuntu Bash requires Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) which [requires Windows 10 Anniversary Update or later (build 1607+)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide). It is not available on Windows Server 2012.

Microsoft has announced [plans to bring WSL support to Windows Server 2016](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloud/2017/05/10/windows-server-for-developers-news-from-microsoft-build-2017/) later in the year 2017.

In the meanwhile, [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) may or may not be an alternative for you.